# Ruby Conditionals Mechanism

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm learning ruby and going through the basics. After playing around with conditionals I've made the following code:

```
x = 10
z = 10
if x==10 && (puts "wow" if x == z)
  puts "hello"
end
```

When I run it I got only "wow". Could somebody explain why "hello" is never printed ?

Thank you.

Comment: Ask yourself what does `puts` return and how that result will impact your conditional ?

Comment: Aside from your question, I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do. Note that `(puts "wow" if x == z)` is not executed if `x != 10`. If you want to `puts` "wow" if `x == z` and `puts` "hello" if both `x = 10` and `z = 10`, then `if x == z; puts "wow"; puts "hello" if x==10; end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `puts` returns `nil`:

```
def test_method
  puts "test"
end

t = test_method #=> "test"
p t #=> nil
```

What that means is `if x==10 && nil` which will be evaluated to `false`. Hence it never gets inside the condition and print "hello".

Comment: I finally got it :). Made a test with `if x==10 && (p "wow" if x == z)` and I got to see the "hello", thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `puts` is actually nil.

Essentially, what the statement says is

```
if x==10 && nil
  puts "hello"
end
```

The value of `nil` is `false`. Any time there's a false in a conditional, the expression will automatically evaluate to false. Therefore, the code block will not be executed.